# What are the differences between the options when accepting communication with hostile ships?

Tags: no-mans-sky

[Per my question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/283181/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-hostile-encounters-in-space) on avoiding hostile ships, an update that is very briefly mentioned in the release logs now allows you to avoid hostile ships

[Atlas Rises](https://www.nomanssky.com/atlas-rises-update/)

> A new HUD has been introduced to improve the experience of space combat. This includes a communicator, which can be used to advance mission steps, or **even to hail pirates before they attack.**

Below is the screen that is displayed when the communication begins.

[image]

I know that...

1. Refuse - initiates space combat
2. Complying/Bargaining - pay your way out
3. Alert Authorities - Haven't found a Defense Chit yet, but I guess stops combat without paying?

I'm unsure of what alerting authorities does, and I know that complying and bargaining are ways to avoid space battles, what are the long term benefit differences between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much digging around, information was finally added to the [Pirate wiki](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Pirate), and it does not appear there are any long term differences between them. It just a matter of how you fight or flee from the pirates

> If the player wants to avoid a pirate attack after being detected, they can use their communicator to speak to the pirate ships before they attack. The player can choose to give their cargo or units to the pirates, attempt to bargain, or call for help if they have a defense chit.

Based on that information, this is what the 4 different options do

1. Refuse: Initiates Combat
2. Bargain: Pay pirates with units to simply go away
3. Comply: Pay pirates with units, which is valued at the inventory they are trying to loot
4. Alert Authorities: Initiates combat, and uses Defense Chit to call for help